# Order of ctor/dtor when returning an object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

**Is this dtor/ctor order normal, and if so, why?**

In the following simple function

```
TemporaryObject SimpleFunction();
{
    TemporaryObject obj = MakeObj();

    // ...

    return obj;   // Stepping through at this point we hit TemporaryObject::dtor, MyObject::ctor
}

// At call site
MyObject obj = SimpleFunction();
```

at the return statement I would expect the MyObject ctor to be called and then the TemporaryObject dtor to be called. (Possibly TemporaryObject would be copied first, but RVO is typical here).

What happens in VS2010 (Debug build) is the TemporaryObject dtor is called first, then the MyObject constructor is called with the destructed object. Looking at the memory addresses confirms it is the destructed object being passed in and if there was any doubt, the destructor side effects are obvious.

(For completeness, the MyObject ctor sets a flag in the TemporaryObject flagging it has been copied. The TemporaryObject dtor asserts this flag is set, which is how I became aware destruction is happening before the 'copy' in this case).

Comment: I really doubt that. Show us the complete minimal code that exibits this problem.

Comment: I doubt it too - example on its way.

Comment: You need to post an example with data fields that are modified in ctors and dector.

Comment: OK - I am an idiot, and with a question like this I should have come to this conclusion _before_ I hit 'Post Question'.
I assumed there was no copy ctor in TemporaryObject because I provided a ctor, but the compiler generates a copy ctor anyway. So it appeared the dtor was being called first, but that was after a copy had been made. So my minimal code exhibits the problem, but made it easy to guess what was happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @Zero: you may consider posting your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimal, Complete Example, with Answer**

Yes, the `dtor` *is* being called before the copy constructor, but not for the reasons you seem to think.

The key observation is `MyObject::dtor` is being called twice (on two different objects in case we're still inclined to jump to crazy compiler bug conclusions). So we guess a copy is happening behind the scenes, and sure enough, despite what you may have heard the compiler *does* generate a copy constructor even when you provide a different constructor.

So, if you uncomment out the copy constructor below you'll get some output that better describes what is going on, and also correctly handles the `mActive` flag

```
struct TemporaryObject
{
    TemporaryObject()
        :
    mActive(true)
    { 
        std::cout << "TemporaryObject::ctor mActive = " << mActive << ", this = " << (void*)this << std::endl;
    }

   /* TemporaryObject(const TemporaryObject& obj)
        :
    mActive(obj.mActive)
    { 
        obj.mActive = false;
        std::cout << "TemporaryObject::copy_ctor mActive = " << mActive << ", this = " << (void*)this << std::endl;
    }*/

    ~TemporaryObject()
    {
        std::cout << "TemporaryObject::dtor mActive = " << mActive << ", this = " << (void*)this << std::endl;
        // assert(!mActive);
    }

    mutable bool mActive;
};

struct MyObject
{
    MyObject(const TemporaryObject& obj)
    {
        std::cout << "MyObject::ctor obj.mActive = " << obj.mActive << ", &obj = " << (void*)(&obj) << std::endl;
        obj.mActive = false;
    }
};

TemporaryObject SimpleFunction()
{
    TemporaryObject obj;

    // Do stuff

    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    MyObject obj = SimpleFunction();
}
```

Output:

```
TemporaryObject::ctor mActive = 1, this = 00EFF4AB
TemporaryObject::dtor mActive = 1, this = 00EFF4AB
MyObject::ctor obj.mActive = 1, &obj = 00EFF4D7
TemporaryObject::dtor mActive = 0, this = 00EFF4D7
```

Comment: "Yes, the dtor is being called before the copy constructor, but not for the reasons you seem to think." You mean not for the reasons **YOU** seem to think. You basically posted an incorrect question claiming something which is wrong, and then refuted it, with the obviously correct answer. You should have deleted the question.

Comment: How do you delete the question? I voted to close it, and only posted the answer because someone suggested I should. And yes, you, You or YOU all refer to the idiot that wrote the question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you see that in debug build. Since in debug version, there is no optimization in returning from function it has the following rule:

```
TemporaryObject::ctor    // Copy constructor
TemporaryObject::dtor    // of function local value that reach end of its scope!
MyObject::ctor           // Create MyObject from returned value
TemporaryObject::dtor    // of function return value
```